# Get the main channel, or the channel of the invite link

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do I get the main channel from a server? Almost all major bots do this. For example, Rythm. The bot sends a message in the main channel that tells you how to use Rythm. That's kind of what I intend to do also, to let people know how to use my bot. If you could help me with this, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guilds have a `defaultChannel` value you can access.

```
guild.defaultChannel.send(`Hello`);
```

Documentation:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=defaultChannel
Though this is **Deprecated** you can still use it unless the `#general` channel is removed.

**Otherwise:**
For the channel the invite refers to:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite 
`invite.channel` is the channel the invite refers to